# How reliable are NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Not so long ago I found out about `NSUserDefaults` and thought: If I can just keep the information my application needs as `NSUserDefaults`, why bother creating a database?  These are the variables my application needs:

- Username     (of type String)
- Coins earned (of type Int16)
- Bucks bought (of type Int16)
- Items bought (of type [String])

How suitable are `NSUserDefaults` as an alternative to using a database? If I do use `NSUserDefaults` instead of a database, would it be reasonable to list all the "buyable" items as an Enum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The [NSUserDefaults documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) clearly states it's primary function is to store user *preferences*:**

> The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences.

Of course there's nothing to stop you from using it otherwise, it's a very cheap and reliable way of reading and writing data, but it's worth knowing that it isn't designed to store application constants and variables.

Furthermore everything you write to it will be available to read in plain text if the user looks into his application container (**and therefore easily editable**). Therefore you probably don't want to be using it for anything that the user can change to get an advantage in your game.

[You might want to look into `NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/) for storing custom objects that could contain your data. This will allow far greater flexibility, and you can encode your data in a non-plain text format.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults is used mostly for preferences not for sensitive data.